# RegEx pattern to not allow special character except underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a special requirement, where i need the achieve the following

1. No Special Character is allowed except `_` in between string.
2. string should not start or end with `_`, `.` and numeric value.
3. underscore should not be allowed before or after any numeric value.

I am able to achieve most of it, but my RegEx pattern is also allowing other special characters.

How can i modify the below RegEx pattern to not allow any special character apart from underscore that to in between strings.

`^[^0-9._]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^0-9._]$`

Comment: Also, below pattern works for me, but i know for sure it's not the best solution.
`^[^0-9\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s]*[^0-9\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s]$`

Comment: Try `/^(?=[A-Z])(?=.*[A-Z]$)(?!.*_\d)(?!.*\d_)\w+$/i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you might do is use [negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert your requirements:

`^(?![0-9._])(?!.*[0-9._]$)(?!.*\d_)(?!.*_\d)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(?![0-9._])` Negative lookahead to assert that the string does not start with `[0-9._]`
- `(?!.*[0-9._]$)` Negative lookahead to assert that the string does not end with `[0-9._]`
- `(?!.*\d_)` Negative lookahead to assert that the string does not contain a digit followed by an underscore
- `(?!.*_\d)` Negative lookahead to assert that the string does not contain an underscore followed by a digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` Match what is specified in the character class one or more times. You can add to the character class what you would allow to match, for example also add a `.`
- `$` Assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR3iE7/2)

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple. Only allow underscore and alphanumeric regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
```

Javascript es6 implementation (works for React):

```
const re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;
re.test(variable_to_test);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your opening and closing sections; `[^0-9._]`, say match ANY character other than those.

So you need to change it to be what you can match.

```
/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z]$/i
```

And since you now said one character is valid:

```
/^[A-Z]([A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z])?$/i
```

Comment: this works well, but there's a little problem, it requires at-least 2 characters to validate. I am wondering there a can solution which can work with single character.

Comment: Well I did add it, this is simple pattern, doubt you need complexity of looking ahead.